# Why am I getting timeout exceptions when I use the WaitForRequestFinishedAsync function?

Tags: c#, .net, playwright, gui-testing

My .NET Playwright tests often skip steps and I have been using `Thread.Sleep()` to make sure it doesn't skip over code.  Instead of this, I want to use `WaitForRequestFinishedAsync()` instead:

```
await page.Locator(".my-class").ClickAsync(); // want to make sure it doesn't skip this line
await page.WaitForRequestFinishedAsync();
```

My error I am receiving:

> System.TimeoutException : Timeout 30000ms exceeded while waiting for event "RequestFinished"

I am probably missing something obvious here, but any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-request-finished), it appears that you can set the timeout time *(defaulting to 30000ms if not defined)* as the second argument in the method definition. Try setting this to `0` to disable the timeout, just to check that the request isn't taking an absurdly long time.

Alternatively, maybe try using `RunAndWaitForRequestFinishedAsync()`, because in this scenario `WaitForRequestFinishedAsync()` may be waiting on a `Task` that was never actually started.